# Sending Ether from private Geth node to Mist Account

Tags: mist, private-blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp, metamask, private-key

I have Sended Ether from my private geth node to an another account  created by metamask.

I have choosed custum RPC to metamsk, with the valide IP and Port, Also i have activated rpc in my geth node.

But i can't see the balance in my metamsk wallet ?

Answer (score 0):

When your transaction gets mined, your balance will be updated.

There is no difference whether which client you choose. If your client is connected to same network, any transaction done by that client will be visible to every other client connected to that network.

In your case, your one client, private geth node, is connected to mainnet chain. And your other client, metamask, is also connected to mainnet chain, so the problem you are faccing is more likely due to following reasons:

- It is taking time for your transaction to get mined.
- You are sending transaction to different network.

I would like to emphasize again, it does not matter which client you are using. Ethereum mainnet is a single chain, and all transactions are visible to everyone.

Comment: No i have my own private blockchain, when i check the balance with command eth.getbalance it work good, but nothing in metamask. i have run metamsk to custum RPC,

Comment: What is the balance it shows in geth? Metamask probably shows eth if it is more than 0.0000009 eth. Not sure though. Please verify.

Comment: 90 ether,  the probleme is in the connection betwen rcpcrossdomain with my metamask

Comment: yes are true. i sended 10000000000000 ether, now i can see balance. but how i can make a lower number? i need to change the Ether price